# How to understand/use Haskell fix function

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators

I see the following code in `xmonad` package:

```
-- | Ignore SIGPIPE to avoid termination when a pipe is full, and SIGCHLD to
-- avoid zombie processes, and clean up any extant zombie processes.
installSignalHandlers :: MonadIO m => m ()
installSignalHandlers = io $ do
    installHandler openEndedPipe Ignore Nothing
    installHandler sigCHLD Ignore Nothing
    (try :: IO a -> IO (Either SomeException a))
      $ fix $ \more -> do
        x <- getAnyProcessStatus False False
        when (isJust x) more
    return ()
```

It seems that this `fix` functions comes from [Data.Function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html)

But I can't understand how it's used here and when would someone use this fix function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fix` is the fundamental tool used for implementing recursion. It can always be replaced by a recursive `let` -- and vice versa, a recursive `let` can be turned into a call to `fix`. In this example,

```
fix $ \more -> do
    x <- getAnyProcessStatus False False
    when (isJust x) more
```

is equivalent to

```
let more = do
        x <- getAnyProcessStatus False False
        when (isJust x) more
in more
```

and is essentially implementing a loop that calls `getAnyProcessStatus False False` until it returns `Nothing`.

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thanks. So `more` here is a dumy variable right? Only used anytime people wants loops? Can there be a counter of loop with this use case?

Comment: @osager Sure, counters are possible.